# How are the votes/delegates in the primaries/caucus counted if the candidate drops out afterwards?

Tags: united-states, election, primaries

Let's say Marco Rubio suspends his campaign. What happens to the delegates he got in the previous primaries and caucuses?

Comment: Now that Rubio *did* drop out, [this live-blog comment](http://fivethirtyeight.com/live-blog/march-15-primaries-ohio-florida-results-presidential-election-2016/?lpup=10017581#livepress-update-10017581) touches on what happens.  As per the question this is a duplicate of: "It depends".